# SQL Queries to be used to find path between two points

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

For the past year I have been working on an Android based
Transit application that runs off a Restful XML based web service
written in PHP.

I have a little trouble properly querying GTFS Data from my MySQL
Database. I have imported the feed files exactly into the Database as
they are in .cvs form (including Field Names).

Does anyone have proper SQL Queries to be used to find path between two points

Answer (score 0):

If that could be done in SQL (non procedural) it would be very interesting. I imagine it would use connect by syntax, or recursive CTEs. But since those aren't suppported by MySQL or SQLite (not sure which one you're asking about), I would go with doing simple queries and doing the processing in Java.

Comment: ok, but why do you want to use SQL to find the paths? You should use SQL to extract the data out of the database and into Java Objects and then use Java algorithms to find the paths.

Comment: this should help you https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/transit-developers/uW2-HAUaelg